# setup file in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

I have made a setup project with visual studio installer project in visual studio.

After installation it gave me 2 setup files like this picture :

[image]

I want to know which one should users install so that they can use that application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Personally I couldn't cope with hidden extensions. Especially when you have `MyProgram.exe.config` which shows as `MyProgram.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Setup.exe** file checks for prerequisites (which are necessary softwares to install before installing your application like in your case its .Net Framework 4.0, Windows Installer etc).

If they are not installed it installs them from vendors website or installs them from folders provided with your installer.

If system has those prerequisites preinstalled, it then directly calls your **msi file** which actually installs your application.

The Name **"setup.exe"** cannot be changed from VS. However msi file name is configurable from VS project.

Comment: can i delete the .msi file just give users .exe setup file?

Comment: @weston: Yes it will not work. Because it do not have application files. They are in msi. Internally after prerequisites checking (and installation) it calls msi. In a big or small project, setup.exe is small, but msi file size increases as application becomes bigger.

Comment: @peteranderson: No you cannot just give exe file. you have to give msi file. Reasons as stated above

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal is .netframework required for installing in other computers?

Comment: If your application needs it, then yes. Prerequisites are based on your application. If your application needs a software to be preinstalled, then that software becomes prerequisites.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19010/discussion-between-peteranderson-and-nikhil-agrawal)

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/3a897533-e9d8-481a-9ea3-1205f427bfb2/) example for a hello world project:

> HelloWorld_Setup.msi
>
> The Windows Installer package for the HelloWorld project. We can
> change its name to something more conventional by modifying the Output
> file name property in the setup project's Property Pages dialog.
>
> Setup.exe
>
> The setup bootstrapper file, which reads Setup.ini to determine the
> required installation tasks. This is the file that is run to start the
> installation. Setup.exe will check for the required .NET runtime and
> prompt users to download it if it is not found on the target PC.

You may also see:

> Setup.ini
>
> The initialization file used by Setup.exe to perform the required
> operations. In a simple setup project like this, Visual Studio .NET
> creates a reference to the MSI file containing the application's
> Windows Installer package along with a reference to the required .NET
> Framework runtime. In more complex installations, it may contain other
> application-specific information.

So `Setup.exe` runs on machines without .net and ensures they have it. The `.msi` will also need [Windows Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8483)

Comment: will .msi install the recommended files like .net and windowsinstaller?

Comment: No, other way around, Setup.exe ensures the prequisits.

Answer (score 0):

the file with .msi extension, it should installs the application in computer.

Comment: will it install the recommended files like .net and windowsinstaller?

Comment: setup.exe will download the files needed and launch the installation of the compatible framework and launch the installation using the msi file afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The two files in your list are probably:

- setup.exe
- sofware setup.msi

Not sure, you need to show extensions. But assuming that I have the extensions correct the basic answer is that the setup.exe is best. However, if your thinking of shipping just that file be very sure to set that on a virgin machine (e.g. a virtual PC).

Now, about what you did not say and perhaps did not ask. If your using VS2010 or earlier and added a VS setup project be aware that VS2012 does not support these projects. Just answering the unasked to, perhaps, answer the real question of adding setup projects. If this is the case check-out ViX. A bit of a learning curve (1-2days) but it is work it.

Alas, I thought that the VS2010 setup project was good.